# (2D) Simple AI is not working when Object pooling is used

Tags: unity

I am building a top down 2D plane game for practice. Here, enemy has an AI script attached. AI script does the following :

1. Determine whether the object is spawned to the left or right of screen.
2. If spawned to the left, rotate object by -90, move till a certain x position is reached, then turn down.

   3. If spawned to the right, rotate object by 90, move till a certain x position is reached, then turn down.

This works when I'm using Instantiate - Destroy method. But causes inconsistent behavior when I  implement object pooling. Inconsistent behavior as in, 1>Planes are spawned, 2>Instead of moving a certain distance horizontally, they just turn down and move downwards. Sometimes they behave as intended, but other times, inconsistenct behavior.

Here is the AI script:

```
public class AI : MonoBehaviour
{
    float angle;
    Vector2 vel, turnVel;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    bool leftSpawn, rightSpawn;

    void OnEnable ()
    {  
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (Vector3.zero);
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        turnVel = new Vector2 (0, -0.5f);
        if (transform.position.x < 0) {
            leftSpawn = true;
            transform.Rotate (0, 0, -90);
            vel = new Vector2 (1, 0);
        }

        if (transform.position.x > 0) {
            rightSpawn = true;
            transform.Rotate (0, 0, 90);
            vel = new Vector2 (-1, 0);
        }
    }

    void Update ()
    {

        if (leftSpawn && transform.position.x < -0.8f)
            rb.velocity = vel;

        if (rightSpawn && transform.position.x > 0.8f) {
            rb.velocity = vel;
        }


        if (rightSpawn && transform.position.x <= 0.8f) {
            rb.velocity = turnVel;
            angle = Mathf.LerpAngle (90, 180, Time.time * 0.9f);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, angle);
        }

        if (leftSpawn && transform.position.x > -0.8f) {
            rb.velocity = turnVel;
            angle = Mathf.LerpAngle (-90, -180, Time.time * 0.9f);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, angle);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the spawning script that doesn't use Pooling. This works fine.

```
public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    int turn = 0;
    public GameObject BF, JU, cam, Hawker, Blenheim;

    void Start ()
    {
        InvokeRepeating ("SpawnEnemy", 0, 3);
    }

    void SpawnEnemy ()
    {

        turn = Random.Range (1, 5);

        if (turn == 1)
            SpawnBF ();
        else if (turn == 2)
            SpawnJU ();
        else if (turn == 3)
            SpawnHawker ();
        else if (turn == 4)
            SpawnBlenheim ();
    }

    void SpawnHawker ()
    {

        float x = -4.47f, y;

        y = cam.transform.position.y + 4.59f;

        Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (x, y, 1);

        GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate (Hawker, pos, Quaternion.identity);

    }

    void SpawnBlenheim ()
    {
        float x = 4.39f, y;

        y = cam.transform.position.y + 4.59f;

        Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (x, y, 1);

        GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate (Blenheim, pos, Quaternion.identity);
    }

    void SpawnBF ()
    {
        float x = -4.47f, y;

        y = cam.transform.position.y + 4.59f;

        Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (x, y, 1);

        GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate (BF, pos, Quaternion.identity);

    }

    void SpawnJU ()
    {
        float x = 4.39f, y;

        y = cam.transform.position.y + 4.59f;

        Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (x, y, 1);

        GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate (JU, pos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

This is the script that pools Enemy planes:

```
public class EnemiesPooler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static EnemiesPooler current;
    public GameObject BF, JU, Hawker, Blenheim;
    int pooledAmount = 10;
    List<GameObject> BFPlane;
    List<GameObject> JUPlane;
    List<GameObject> HawkerPlane;
    List<GameObject> BlenheimPlane;

    void Start ()
    {
        BFPlane = new List<GameObject> ();
        JUPlane = new List<GameObject> ();
        HawkerPlane = new List<GameObject> ();
        BlenheimPlane=new List<GameObject>();
        current = this;

        for (int i=0; i<pooledAmount; i++) {
            GameObject bf = (GameObject)Instantiate (BF,Vector3.zero,Quaternion.identity);
            bf.SetActive (false);
            BFPlane.Add (bf);

            GameObject ju = (GameObject)Instantiate (JU,Vector3.zero,Quaternion.identity);
            ju.SetActive (false);
            JUPlane.Add (ju);

            GameObject hawker = (GameObject)Instantiate (Hawker,Vector3.zero,Quaternion.identity);
            hawker.SetActive (false);
            HawkerPlane.Add (hawker);

            GameObject blenheim = (GameObject)Instantiate (Blenheim,Vector3.zero,Quaternion.identity);
            blenheim.SetActive (false);
            BlenheimPlane.Add (blenheim);

        }

    }

    public GameObject GetBF ()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<BFPlane.Count; i++) {
            if (!BFPlane [i].activeInHierarchy)
                return BFPlane [i];
        }

        return null;
    }

    public GameObject GetJU ()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<JUPlane.Count; i++)
            if (!JUPlane [i].activeInHierarchy) {
                return JUPlane [i];
            }
        return null;
    }

    public GameObject GetHawker ()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<HawkerPlane.Count; i++)
            if (!HawkerPlane [i].activeInHierarchy) {
                return HawkerPlane [i];
            }
        return null;
    }

    public GameObject GetBlenheim ()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<BlenheimPlane.Count; i++)
            if (!BlenheimPlane [i].activeInHierarchy) {
                return BlenheimPlane [i];
            }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the script that spawns using Object Pooling. This is the one causing inconsistent behavior.

```
public class PoolTest : MonoBehaviour {
    int turn=0;
    float left=-4.47f,right=4.39f,yPos=4.59f,zpos=1,y,rotClockwise=270,rotCounterClockwise=-270;
    public Transform cam;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        InvokeRepeating ("SpawnEnemy",0,3);

    }

    void SpawnEnemy()
    {   

        turn = Random.Range (1, 5);

         if(turn == 1)
            SpawnBF ();
        else if (turn == 2)
            SpawnJU ();
        else if (turn == 3)
            SpawnHawker ();
        else if (turn == 4)
            SpawnBlenheim ();
    }

    void SpawnBF()
    {  

        int spawnSide;
        Vector3 pos;
        float rot;

        y = cam.position.y + yPos;
        spawnSide = Random.Range (0,2);
        if (spawnSide == 0) {

            pos = new Vector3 (left, y, zpos);

        } 
        else {
            pos = new Vector3 (right, y, zpos);

        }

        GameObject obj=EnemiesPooler.current.GetBF();
        if (obj == null)
            return;

        obj.transform.position=pos;
        obj.SetActive (true);
    }

    void SpawnJU()
    {

        int spawnSide;
        Vector3 pos;

        spawnSide = Random.Range (0,2);
        if (spawnSide == 0)
            pos = new Vector3 (left, y, zpos);
        else
            pos = new Vector3 (right,y,zpos);

        GameObject obj=EnemiesPooler.current.GetJU();
        if (obj == null)
            return;
        obj.transform.position=pos;
        obj.SetActive (true);

    }

    void SpawnHawker()
    {

        int spawnSide;
        Vector3 pos;

        spawnSide = Random.Range (0,2);
        if (spawnSide == 0)
            pos = new Vector3 (left, y, zpos);
        else
            pos = new Vector3 (right,y,zpos);

        GameObject obj=EnemiesPooler.current.GetHawker();
        if (obj == null)
            return;

        obj.transform.position=pos;
        obj.SetActive (true);

    }

    void SpawnBlenheim()
    {

        int spawnSide;
        Vector3 pos;

        spawnSide = Random.Range (0,2);
        if (spawnSide == 0) {
            pos = new Vector3 (left, y, zpos);
        }
        else
            pos = new Vector3 (right,y,zpos);

        GameObject obj=EnemiesPooler.current.GetBlenheim();
        if (obj == null)
            return;

        obj.transform.position=pos;
        obj.SetActive (true);

    }

    void Update () {
        y = cam.position.y + yPos;
    }
}
```

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out what is causing this inconsistency. But, couldn't find any solution. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick about pooling complex/customizable objects is to reset their state before returning to a pool. So when you fetch from a pool, fetched object always be the same as instantiated one. I don't see any code that return object to pool.

I may suppose that when you init your pooler component some of AI get working before you disable objects. Between this two lines:

```
        GameObject bf = (GameObject)Instantiate (BF,Vector3.zero,Quaternion.identity);
        bf.SetActive (false);
```

Right after Instantiation of `bf` object `bf.OnEnable()` method was called causing the object to do some code and rotate. After that `bf.SetActive (false)` is called, but it's too late.

To check this out, add some debug code to your EnemiesPooler.Start() method:

```
void Start ()
{
    BFPlane = new List<GameObject> ();
    JUPlane = new List<GameObject> ();
    HawkerPlane = new List<GameObject> ();
    BlenheimPlane=new List<GameObject>();
    current = this;

    for (int i=0; i<pooledAmount; i++) {
        Debug.Log("Instantiation"); // here
        GameObject bf = (GameObject)Instantiate (BF,Vector3.zero,Quaternion.identity);
        Debug.Log("Instantiated. Deactivation"); // here
        bf.SetActive (false);
        Debug.Log("Deactivated"); // and here
        BFPlane.Add (bf);

        GameObject ju = (GameObject)Instantiate (JU,Vector3.zero,Quaternion.identity);
        ju.SetActive (false);
        JUPlane.Add (ju);

        GameObject hawker = (GameObject)Instantiate (Hawker,Vector3.zero,Quaternion.identity);
        hawker.SetActive (false);
        HawkerPlane.Add (hawker);

        GameObject blenheim = (GameObject)Instantiate (Blenheim,Vector3.zero,Quaternion.identity);
        blenheim.SetActive (false);
        BlenheimPlane.Add (blenheim);

    }

}
```

And in the AI.OnEnable() method:

```
void OnEnable ()
{  
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (Vector3.zero);
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    turnVel = new Vector2 (0, -0.5f);
    if (transform.position.x < 0) {
        leftSpawn = true;
        transform.Rotate (0, 0, -90);
        Debug.Log("Turned -90*"); // here
        vel = new Vector2 (1, 0);
    }

    if (transform.position.x > 0) {
        rightSpawn = true;
        transform.Rotate (0, 0, 90);
        Debug.Log("Turned 90*"); // and here
        vel = new Vector2 (-1, 0);
    }
}
```

After that run your code and you will see sequence of messages in the console. I suppose that between 'Instantiat**ion**' and 'Deactivat**ed**' will be 'Turned' message.

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking, I decided to use the EnemySpawner script only to fetch planes. I moved the positioning logic to the AI script, so positioning, rotation and movement would be up to the spawned plane.